# Bundle ios error Deezer Api

Tags: ios, deezer

I'm having trouble implementing the Deezer api inside my project. Everything actually works well expect for the login. I keep getting an error saying my bundle id is incorrect. I've already tried adding an ios bundle id in myapps on the Deezer site. i changed the "app id" but i'm still getting an error. maybe someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure all information filled into Deezer developer website are good.

Go to http://developers.deezer.com/myapps/app , clic "Edit Application" and check the datas.
Into "Basic info", your application name and application domain must be specified.
Into "IOS application", the "IOS bundle ID" must be specified too. The value is like "com.companyname.appname"

Finally check that the application id you use with the [DeezerConnect initWithAppId:delegate]  method is valid.